# Configuring IIS7/MVC to load a particular MvcApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I currently have two MVC4 projects, one is the *main product* and the other one is a **derived product** that has a reference to (inherits) the first one.

Locally I have no trouble to debug the **derived product**, but when deploying the **derived product** on IIS I get to see the *main product* because it seems it's DLL is loaded first or something like that (I assumed this because changing the name of these DLLS affects the product that is displayed when reaching the host).

### To resume:

Two projects:

1. Product.ASP
2. Product.Derived.ASP -> Product.ASP (references)

When:

- Debugging locally through visual studio or iis express:

  Working as I expect: Product.Derived.ASP is loaded and displayed
- Deployed on IIS server:

  Not working as I expect: Product.ASP is loaded and displayed (affected by the naming of the dlls)

---

How can I tell IIS (or .NET, whatever) to load some DLL first? Is there a way to override the behavior that will load one or another MvcApplication (HttpApplication)?

I've also read about Handlers but have no idea how to apply my case to it

Comment: did you publish the "deriver product" as a separate site ? right click on the project > publish

Comment: Yes, only the derived product is published, but since there is a reference, both dlls are outputed to the publish directory